# Large amount of data transfer

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables A and B. Table A has 36460090 records while Table B has few lesser records than Table A. Table B is a subset of Table A. I want to transfer only those records from Table A to Table B which are not in Table B. There is no primary key in both tables. Also Table A and Table B both might contain duplicate records.
How can I carry out this transfer?
This is the code below:

```
select a.* , b.id 
into #temp 
from TableA a 
left join TableB b 
on a.id=b.id , a.var1=b.var1 ,a.var2=b.var2 .... , a.var12=b.var12
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried?

Comment: select a.*  , b.id
into #temp
from TableA a
left join TableB b
on a.id=b.id , a.var1=b.var1 ,a.var2=b.var2 .... , a.var12=b.var12

Now #temp contains more records than TableA and you might know why is that

Comment: @abdulsammad, you should place your code in the question.

Comment: Thanks! any suggestion regarding the solution? @hoss

Comment: Without primary key it is likely, that the most efficient way is to truncate table B and copy everything from A into empty B.

Answer (score 0):

to select rows in a that are not in b:

```
select a.*
from a
where a.id in(select id from a
              except
              select id from b);
```

2nd solution:

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists(select 1
                 from b
                 where b.id = a.id);
```

Comment: Will this work if Id is not a primary key meaning there could same value of id for different records? 
@stevanuz

Comment: as far as both tables have id column and compatible data type, then set operation should work. in terms of performance without index, it will not perform well because it will just scan.

Comment: if there are two records in A with id = 2 but one record in B with id = 2 then this statement will not select the second record of A with id = 2

Comment: you are right, they only return distinct, unfortunately no except all in sql server

Comment: try with not exists, it will return duplicate from a